# Javascript parser wont work anymore. Nothing happens when the submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, button, submit

I recently found this piece of javascript for a game that I play which basically makes my life easier in the game by doing some parsing. The script was working great when I first used it but then I stopped using it for a few weeks as I had less time to play the game and therefore use the script. I started again yesterday and suddenly, the script no longer worked and I couldnt parse the info that I needed. It no longer works when I click the submit button after the info is put into the text box.

Could anyone help me in finding out what is wrong and why it wont work anymore?

Here is the script and here it is on a website (incase what I posted below got messed up or whatever: www.cnparser.webs.com

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Recruitment Parser</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
var pageSource = document.getElementById('pgsource');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
var bbcodeBox = document.getElementById('nobb');
var outputArea = document.getElementById('output');

submitButton.onclick = function()
{
    var cyberMessageLink = "http:\/\/www.cybernations.net/send_message.asp?Nation_ID=";
    var cleanUp = pageSource.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 >]/g, "");
    var rulerNames = cleanUp.match(/titleRuler[A-Za-z0-9_ ]{3,}(?=>)/gi);
    var nationID = cleanUp.match(/ageaspNationID[0-9]{3,}/g);

    if(bbcodeBox.checked)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<rulerNames.length; i++)
        {
            if(i%25==0)
            {
                outputArea.innerHTML+="[url="+cyberMessageLink+nationID[i].substring(14)+"]"+rulerNames[i].substring(11)+"[/url]" + "<br>";
                continue;
            }
            outputArea.innerHTML+=rulerNames[i].substring(11) + "<br>";
            if(i%24==0)outputArea.innerHTML+="<br>";
        }
    } else {

        for(var i=0; i<rulerNames.length; i++)
        {
            if(i%25==0)outputArea.innerHTML+="<br>";
            outputArea.innerHTML+=rulerNames[i].substring(11) + "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <textarea id="pgsource" cols="80" rows="20"></textarea><br/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>Style</b><br>
        <input id="nobb" type="checkbox">BBcode</input><br>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="submit">Submit</button><br><br>
<span id="output"></span>
<!-- --><script type="text/javascript"      src="http://static.websimages.com/static/global/js/webs/usersites/escort.js"></script>   <script type="text/javascript">if(typeof(urchinTracker)=='function'){_uacct="UA-230305-  2";_udn="none";_uff=false;urchinTracker();}</script></body>

</html>
```

Comment: "I recently found this piece of javascript for a game that I play which basically makes my life easier in the game by doing some parsing. " are you trying to hack the game? and you need help for this?

Comment: No, its not a hack, its a parser. You input the page source code of the list of nation and ruler names for the game and the parser outputs the names of the rulers in a single list. In the game, the ruler names are hard to copy and paste to message so this makes it easier to copy and paste the names for messaging.

Answer (score 0):

From the linked site:

> If this stops working email: gnomy@hushmail.com

Did you email Gnomy?

Comment: I did but didnt get any reply. The parser is over 5 years old so I dont think he would even use that email anymore.